# ¡Objeto no localizado! error 404 PHP XAMPP

Tags: php, html

Estoy trabajando con `XAMPP` y `PHP`. y en el código incluyo un documento php con la función include, pero cuando abro el explorador este siempre me abre otro archivo el cual yo no incluí con la función include.

codigo `PHP`:

```
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Documento sin título</title>
  <style>
    body {

      background-color: #614D49;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="calculadora.php">
    <input type="text" name="num1">
    <input type="text" name="num2">

    <select name="operacion">
      <option>Suma</option>
      <option>Resta</option>
      <option>Multiplicación</option>
      <option>División</option>
      <option>Módulo</option>
      <option>Incremento</option>
      <option>Decremento</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">

  </form>
<?php
include("calcu2.php");// este es el archivo calcu2.php
if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
  $numero1=$_POST["num1"];
  $numero2=$_POST["num2"];
  $operacion=$_POST["operacion"];
  calcular($operacion);
  }

?>





</body>
</html>
```

y este es el archivo `calcu2.php` que esta incluido en el archivo principal:

```
<style>
.resultado{
    font-size: 550%;

}
</style>
<?php
function calcular($operacion){
global $numero1;
global $numero2;
if (!strcmp($operacion,"Suma")) {
    $a=$numero1 + $numero2;
  echo "<p class='resultado'>$a</p>" ;

} 
if (!strcmp($operacion,"Resta")){
    $b=$numero1 - $numero2;
  echo "<p class='resultado'>$b</p>" ;

  } 
  if (!strcmp($operacion,"Multiplicación")){
      $c=$numero1 * $numero2;
    echo "<p class='resultado'>$c</p>" ;
  } 
  if (!strcmp($operacion,"División")){
      $d=$numero1 / $numero2;
    echo "<p class='resultado'>$d</p>" ;
  } 
  if (!strcmp($operacion,"Módulo")){
      $c=$numero1 % $numero2;
    echo "<p class='resultado'>$c</p>" ;
  }
  if (!strcmp($operacion,"Incremento")){
    $numero1++;
    $c=$numero1;
  echo "<p class='resultado'>$c</p>" ;
}
if (!strcmp($operacion,"Decremento")){
  $c=$numero1--;
echo "<p class='resultado'>$c</p>" ;
}


}
  ?>
```

y esto es lo que pasa cuando intento hacer algún calculo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven me redirecciona a otro archivo y no al `calcu2.php` que es el que yo especifico en el código

Comment: Hiciste mal el copy/paste, se te olvido quitar calculadora.php del action en el formulario. dejalo vacio para que funcione tu include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en el formulario estas remitiendo a calculadora.php en el action=""

deberias colocar el action redirigiendo al mismo archivo, quedaria asi:

```
<body>
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="num1">
    <input type="text" name="num2">

    <select name="operacion">
      <option>Suma</option>
      <option>Resta</option>
      <option>Multiplicación</option>
      <option>División</option>
      <option>Módulo</option>
      <option>Incremento</option>
      <option>Decremento</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">

  </form>
<?php
include("calcu2.php");// este es el archivo calcu2.php
if(isset($_POST["enviar"])){
  $numero1=$_POST["num1"];
  $numero2=$_POST["num2"];
  $operacion=$_POST["operacion"];
  calcular($operacion);
  }

?>
```

espero te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

El nombre calcu2.php no lo vas a ver en la barra de dirección; esto porque lo estás incluyendo como contenido del archivo principal (que por el mensaje de error, se debería llamar calculadora.php).

Si renombras el archivo principal como calculadora.php (que es lo que invocas en el submit del formulario), debe funcionarte sin problema.